# ANTLR cannot generate Javascript code as of version 4.5

Tags: javascript, antlr, antlr4

when i try to generate the listener/visitor ... for my Grammar I get the following error : ANTLR cannot generate Javascript code as of version 4.5

Does anybody knows how to fix it? I still can generate C# and Java Code.

Comment: Couldn't find any hint to that fact. Older Versions like 4.4 and 4.3 doesn't work either

Comment: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/releases as statet here it should work

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From [the docs](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/javascript-target.md#how-to-create-a-javascript-lexer-or-parser):

> This is pretty much the same as creating a Java lexer or parser, except you need to specify the language target, for example:
>
> ```
> $ antlr4 -Dlanguage=JavaScript MyGrammar.g4
> ```
>
> For a full list of antlr4 tool options, please visit the tool documentation page.

It is possible that you are targeting `Javascript` instead of the required `JavaScript` (note the case); observe the difference when I execute the two:

```
╭─{ yaauie@celeborn:~/Desktop/tmp-20160108 }
╰─○ antlr4 -Dlanguage=JavaScript Hello.g4
[success]

╭─{ yaauie@celeborn:~/Desktop/tmp-20160108 }
╰─○ antlr4 -Dlanguage=Javascript Hello.g4
error(31):  ANTLR cannot generate Javascript code as of version 4.5.1
[error: 1]
```

Comment: That's right, it should be "JavaScript", with that exact capitalization. [List of language targets](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/targets.md).

Answer (score 3):

You need "JavaScript", not "Javascript".

The exact language values for supported languages are:

**Java:**

```
antlr4 -Dlanguage=Java MyGrammar.g4
```

**JavaScript:**

```
antlr4 -Dlanguage=JavaScript MyGrammar.g4
```

**C#:**

```
antlr4 -Dlanguage=CSharp MyGrammar.g4
```

**Python 3:**

```
antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python3 MyGrammar.g4
```

**Python 2:**

```
antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python2 MyGrammar.g4
```

**Go:**

```
antlr4 -Dlanguage=Go MyGrammar.g4
```

**C++:**

```
antlr4 -Dlanguage=Cpp MyGrammar.g4
```

**Swift:**

```
antlr4 -Dlanguage=Swift MyGrammar.g4
```

**PHP:**

```
antlr4 -Dlanguage=PHP MyGrammar.g4
```

Source: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/targets.md and follow the language-specific links.

Answer (score 1):

I was working with ATNLR to parse hive queries in java and had a similar issue. It turns out that I was missing the case. Instead of **Java** I was writing **java**

`$>antlr -Dlanguage=java Hplsql.g4
-->error(31):  ANTLR cannot generate java code as of version 4.7.1`

`$>antlr -Dlanguage=Java Hplsql.g4
-->Success`

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to execute:

`antlr4 Arithmetic.g4 -Dlanguage=cSharp`

I was getting a message:

> ANTLR cannot generate cSharp code as of version 4.12.0

Just found the issue. Antlr language is **CASE SENSITIVE**

This works:

antlr4 Arithmetic.g4 -Dlanguage=**CSharp**

I hope this helps someone else.